# Elastic Beanstalk deployment in AWS by uploading zip (after downloading it from EB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm learning Elastic Beanstalk. We have an application which is deployed with EB.

I'm able to download the zip of the deployment.

Now is my question: am I able to adapt the content of the zip and recreate the zip and deploy again? Because this does not seem to work for me:

```
Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-WriteApplication1, Infra-WriteApplication2, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-PostAppDeploy ..
```

The application (which I don't know) is also in a git. Is the zipfile on AWS the application after the build + deploy so is the approach I'm taking not possible? Am I trying to redeploy an already build application which includes changes?

In the logs I see some: AWSDeployment.log. Is this part changing the content which is in the zip on AWS?

Comment: How are you pulling down the zip file from elastic beanstalk?

Comment: @toddg I go to the overview from old deployments and there are version numbers and zipfiles of the deploy. I download the zipfile there. (I click on 'deploy' and click than on 'see list of old deployments'

Comment: Have you tried pulling the git repo, making changes then zipping and deploying that one? Also, I recommend taking a look at the eb command line utility, greatly simplifies the deploy process once you get the hang of it.